# Python, selenium find_element_by_link_text not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape a website. Where in I have to press a link. for this purpose, I am using selenium library with chrome drive.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGnewUI/Search/Home/Home?partnerid=25222&siteid=5011&noback=1&fromSM=true#Applications'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

link = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Don't have an account yet?")
link.click()
```

But it is not working. Any ideas why it is not working? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it done in several ways. Here is one of such. I've used `driver.execute_script()` command to force the clicking. You should not go for hardcoded delay as they are very inconsistent.

Modified script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGnewUI/Search/Home/Home?partnerid=25222&siteid=5011&noback=1&fromSM=true#Applications'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

item = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[ng-click='newAccntScreen()']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",item)
```

Comment: Hi, How did you come up with "arguments[0].click();" & "a[ng-click='newAccntScreen()']". sorry I am new to these.